# how to push an input bar out of the way of another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, transition

im not sure if this is possible but i have these two input bars next to each other.  i am trying to have one of the bars stay open until the other is clicked then the first one closes and it stays as well.  i have something similar using transition with "autofocus" but when you click on my site, the bar closes.

javascript would work great if anyone could do that

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trade2day1/xqdGG/1/)

any help?

HTML:

```
<div id='Sidebar'>
<div id='SMBar'>
    <div id="input-bars">
        <!-- SEARCH BAR -->
        <div id="SearchBar">
            <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="URL">
                <input type="text" class="search-text-input" placeholder="Search Posts..." name="q" />
            </form>
            <div class="tfclear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- EMAIL BAR -->
        <div id="FollowByEmail1">
            <form action="URL" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('URL', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
                <p>
                    <input autofocus="autofocus" class="follow-by-email-address" placeholder="Updates by Email..." type="text" name="email" />
                </p>
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="uri" />
                <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Sidebar {
width: 270px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
height: 500px;
}
#SMBar {
border: 1px solid transparent;
margin: 5px;
height: 405px;
}
#input-bars {
border: 1px solid transparent;
margin: 5px;
height: 30px;
}
input {
height: 25px;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Play;
padding-left: 30px;
width: 0px;
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 1s;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #dddddd;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #dddddd;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #dddddd;
}
input:focus {
width: 170px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000000;
}
.follow-by-email-address {
background-image: url(http://imageshack.com/a/img703/8868/iavu.png);
padding-left: 30px;
margin: -12px 0px 0px 2px;
float: left;
}
.search-text-input {
background-image: url(http://imageshack.com/a/img34/9278/cw35.png);
padding-left: 30px;
float: right;
margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: It would be very do-able with JavaScript, but I think the elements would have to be siblings in order to use CSS alone-> see [General Sibling Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors). Is using JavaScript an option here?

Comment: [This is as close as I could get using CSS Only](http://jsfiddle.net/nJh99/1/)

Comment: thanks.. when i add <form> around the inputs it messes it up and i cant figure out how to get it to work,

when editing my own code i got as far as getting the search on the right small, email big but when i clicked search the email wouldnt move..  i have no idea how to write java script (for now) but it is an option if you can tell me where to put it

Comment: I'm super confused. It looks as though you have what you want working in the JSFiddle link in your question. I'd love to help you out, but your question is kind of vague. Tell me if I don't understand the problem. So, you want two text fields (aka `<input type="text"/>` elements) next to each other. When you focus the first one, it grows wider as the second one shrinks. On blur, the first one shrinks as the second one grows wider. If blurring the second one, both go back to 50% (or to whatever proportions you want). Am I missing something?

Comment: it is working but only to an extent.. if you click away from the input, say the website, the one in focus is no longer in focus & shinks into icons.. i want the last one that was in focus to stay in focus (or streched) until the other is clicked (the would be icon) even if something else was clicked.. it sounds like something javascript would be needed but i dont know how to write javascript yet or where to put it

Comment: may this would be compromise ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/xqdGG/4/

Comment: eicto, it doesnt look like it made any difference

Comment: @Schmalzy you know any javascript that would fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cj47/)

I changed the `.follow-by-email-address`'s initial width to be 170px and removed the `input:focus` CSS selector then added this script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.follow-by-email-address').focus(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: 170
        }, 500);
        $('.search-text-input').animate({
            width: 0
        },500);
    });

    $('.search-text-input').focus(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: 170
        }, 500);
        $('.follow-by-email-address').animate({
            width: 0
        },500);
    });
});
```

Comment: awesome, never used jquery so where do i put it? i am using a blogger hosted page so im using a widget that can read javascript but usually just put it straight in the html using <script>

Comment: First you would add a reference to the jquery library. something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`. Although your site may already be using jQuery... you should look into that. Then AFTER jquery, add the script above in a `<script>` tag. Note: I added `$(document).ready(function(){` to the script above... you will need that part when adding it to your page, but you don't need it in jsFiddle.